# Using Boolean Algebra to prove k-map result

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have been stuck on a homework problem which asks first to simplify a boolean equation using a k-map and second to reach the same result using boolean algerbra. The k-map was no issue and I have verified the k-map result, but no matter what I do, I am unable to achieve the same result using algerbra techniques. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Original Equation: A'C (A'BD)' + A'BC'D' + AB'C

Kmap Solution: A'BD' + B'C

[Written Work on Whiteboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGvbJ.jpg)

Comment: Are you familiar with the *consensus* theorem?  You may know it under the name of resolution.  It says that $ab+b'c+ac = ab+b'c$.

Comment: I am uncertain how to apply it. Every way I attempt it, I always end up with A'BC' + A'BD' + B'C

Comment: Your first term is incorrect.  Can you show your work?

Comment: I added a link to my written out work on the main question.

Comment: Your board work is correct; you just copied one term incorrectly.  From A'CD' + A'BD' + B'C observe that the first term is the consensus term of the other two; hence it can be dropped.  To apply consensus, you match A'D' to $a$, B to $b$ and C to $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done everything correctly, but to get to the desired answer, let's pick it up a few lones earlier, where you have:

$B'C + A'CD' + A'BC'D'$

From here:

$= B'C + A'BCD' + A'B'CD' + A'BC'D'$ (By expansion of A'CD')

$= B'C + A'BCD' + A'BC'D'$ (Third term got Absorbed by first)

$= B'C + A'BD'$

Comment: I just finished looking through the instructors manual for this questions and this is exactly as it is listed. I just don't understand why I am allowed to throw the B term back in?

Comment: You mean in the first step I do?  It's because in general $A = AB + AB'$. So I expand A'CD' to A'BCD' + AB'CD'